How to refresh access token and set it in cookies in NextJS server component?
I am building a website using NextJS as frontend, FastAPI as backend, clerk for auth. I need to get JWT access token from clerk and set it to cookies for caching.
I write a server action, the logic is:
// 1. try to get "access_token" from cookies
// 2. If not found or expired, get new one from clerk using getToken() and set cookies
I can call this action from client component, but not server component
// The server action
"use server";

import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

import { CLERK_PEM_PUBLIC_KEY } from "@/config";

/**
 * Get the access token from cookies.
 *
 * If the token is not found or expired, get a new token from Clerk.
 *
 * @returns {Promise<{ token: string, isNewToken: boolean }>}
 */
export const getAccessTokenAction = async () => {
  let accessToken = cookies().get("access_token");
  if (accessToken) {
    try {
      await jwt.verify(accessToken.value, CLERK_PEM_PUBLIC_KEY);
      return {
        token: accessToken.value,
        isNewToken: false,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof jwt.TokenExpiredError) {
        // Token expired, do nothing and just break the if block and get a new token
      } else throw error;
    }
  }
  const { getToken } = auth();
  const newAccessToken = await getToken();
  if (!newAccessToken) throw new Error("Failed to get access token");

  cookies().set("access_token", newAccessToken);
  return {
    token: newAccessToken,
    isNewToken: true,
  };
};

The client page works well:
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { getAccessTokenAction } from "../_actions/get-access-token";

const ClientPage = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string | undefined>();
  const [isNewToken, setIsNewToken] = useState<boolean | undefined>();
  const handleClick = () => {
    getAccessTokenAction().then(({ token, isNewToken }) => {
      setToken(token);
      setIsNewToken(isNewToken);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>Click to get access token</Button>
      <div>{token}</div>
      <div>{isNewToken}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ClientPage;

But the server page throw errors：Error: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options
import { getAccessTokenAction } from "../_actions/get-access-token";

const ServerPage = async () => {
  const { token, isNewToken } = await getAccessTokenAction();

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{isNewToken}</div>
      <div>{token}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ServerPage;


Have you found any solution?
I have NestJS as backend and NextJS as frontend. And I can't get them to work correctly for a week now regarding cookies.
And the problem is that I just can't move everything to the client component, because the API has to be accessed sometimes from the server side, and if the AccessToken is expired, I have to refresh it with RefreshToken.
But how can I communicate this to the client and refresh the cookie in the browser?
I've seen a couple of solutions via proxy on Router Handler and spoofing in Middleware, but they only work partially.
